# Track which hyperlink called a slide

Tags: vba, macos, powerpoint

A quiz was created using PowerPoint. Each question has multiple-choice answers. For each answer, a hyperlink was created to either send it to a slide indicating a correct answer (only one) or a slide indicating an incorrect answer (all the others). It needs to capture which answer the user clicked. The correct one is easy because only one answer will open the correct slide, but all the incorrect answers go to the same slide.

Is there a way to capture what object/hyperlink ID/Name, etc. that "called" a slide? I want to avoid writing separate Events for each hyperlink. Is there a way to capture it in the Application Event?

I have the following code.

Class Code:

```vb
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application 
    
Private Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(1).SlideNumber    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint supports action settings to run a macro. Define the macro as follows:

```
Sub ClickMe(Shp As Shape)
MsgBox Shp.Name
End Sub
```

Now, assign the action setting to run this macro and see how the shape reference is passed along. You can use that to avoid using events altogether. Drive the quiz using code.

Comment: The action settings are already set to a hyperlink. I don't think it could be set to a macro as well.

Comment: You can’t do both but if you set it to macro then in your macro you can open the correct slide.

Comment: Note that this won't work on Mac.  There's a workaround that works on PC or Mac here:  Determine which shape was clicked
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00141_Determine_which_shape_was_clicked.htm